# Is there a good testing tool for web interfaces with support of VBScript?

Tags: testing, vbscript, automated-tests

I have to performs testing on an old legacy tools that's web based and make a huge use of VBScript, rather than JavaScript. So, yes, it's a IE-only tool.

Usually, I tend to use WebTest to performs such testing, but it does not support VBScript, making it unusable in that case.

So, is there a testing framework that support VBScript? (please, please, please!!!)

Comment: unit test tool or integration test tool?

Comment: I'm okay for both, as long as it can interact within an IE environment for the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a commercial tool called TestComplete that lets you do Web testing using VBScript. See [web page](http://www.testcomplete.com) for more details.

Comment: A few years have passed since my answer, and in the meantime, I no longer can recommend TestComplete to anyone anymore (due to quality issues, mediocre support, and rising maintenance prices). Unfortunately, Stackoverflow does not let me delete this answer.